# Outlook vba Send email when Task Completed

Tags: vba, email, vbscript, outlook

I develop a solution with VBScript for Task Management in Outlook.

My problem is that I try to send an email notification when the Outlook task is marked as complete.

I use the the following code for test but the problem is when a task changes to complete, this automatically changes these 3 properties:

- Percentproperty
- CompleteProperty
- StatusProperty.

So the result is that 3 emails gets sent when the Task gets marked as complete.

How can do it to send only one email notification when the task completed?

Below is my code but now to send email to present what property changes

```
Sub Item_PropertyChange(ByVal Name)
    If Item.Status=2 Then
        MsgBox "The " & Name & " property changed."
    End If
End Sub
```

My full code

```
Sub Item_PropertyChange(ByVal Name)
    Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    If Item.Status = 2 Then
        With oMsg
            .To = "myemailaddress"
            .Subject = "Task Completed"
            .Body = Item.Subject
            .Send
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Good idea. The way to do this is to post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: After days finally i found the solution and i would like to share it    The problem was that must use 2 if statements if you want to check if task completed. First check the status of the item and after check status of the item percentcomplete for example. Unless it will run forever. An example was my problem above.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of my problem is the following

You must use 2 if statements if you want to check if task completed. First check the status of the item and after check status of the item percentcomplete for example. Unless it will run forever. An example was my problem above.
Find the code if someone wants to use it

```
Sub Item_PropertyChange(ByVal Name)
    Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set objControl = objPage.Controls("TextBox1")
    Set objPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2")

    Set objControl = objPage.Controls("TextBox1")
    MyValue= objControl.Value

    'If Statement to Trigegr an action When Task Completed
    'To work correct must have second If Statement.
    'If you check just for Complete = True, it will run forever. 

    If Item.Status = olTaskComplete And Item.IsRecurring = False then
     If Item.PercentComplete = 100 then

        With oMsg   
          .Recipients.Add(MyValue)

          .Subject = "Task Completed "
          .Body = Item.Subject
          .Send
        End With

     end if
    end if
```

End Sub